c++ access elements in a vector and map + std::any nested
I want to add, edit, and read content in a nested vector and map
typedef std::map<std::string, std::any> T_map;
typedef std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::any>> T_vector;

T_map data;
data["Total"] = 50;
data["Name"] = std::string {"abc123"};
int Total = std::any_cast<int>(data["Total"]);//read
std::string Named = std::any_cast<std::string>(data["Name"]);//read

data["Functions"] = T_vector(50); //initialized with size 50
std::any_cast<T_map>(std::any_cast<T_vector>(data["Functions"])[0])["addr"] = 123456; //There are no data changes
int addr = std::any_cast<int>(std::any_cast<T_map>(std::any_cast<T_vector>(data["Functions"])[1])["addr"]); //read error 

I think this error is because adding information in line 11 was not as expected, leading to an error in the code in line 12.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_any_cast' what():  bad any_cast
Is there any other solution or alternative that is more understandable?

std::any_cast<T_map&>(std::any_cast<T_vector&>(data["Functions"])[0])["addr"] = 123456; Note the ampersands.  When you do e.g. std::any_cast<T_vector>(data["Functions"]) (without the ampersand) you get back a temporary that is a copy of the vector stored in the any; changes you make to that copy don't affect the original. When you do std::any_cast<T_vector&>(...) you get a reference to the vector actually stored inside the any.

In addition to what @IgorTandetnik mentioned, you have one std::any_cast<T_map> too many, because elements in your T_vectors are std::maps, not std::any<std::map>>s. An also, you have a typo: when trying to access the stored data, you use index 1 instead of 0. To sum it up, the last two lines should be: std::any_cast<T_vector&>(data["Functions"])[0]["addr"] = 123456; and int addr = std::any_cast<int>(std::any_cast<T_vector&>(data["Functions"])[0]["addr"]);

Thank you both for helping me solve my problem.
